# What do square brackets around an identifier mean in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

In certain SQL dialects, identifiers in square brackets have special semantics. What is the effect of enclosing an identifier in square brackets in SQLite?

As an example, SQLite (at least as of 3.40.1) accepts the following table definition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Banana] (
  [Weight] REAL NOT NULL,
  [Color] TEXT DEFAULT 'yellow' NOT NULL,
  [Ripe] BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

You can then insert and select bananas:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Banana] ([Weight]) VALUES (1.0), (2.0), (3.0);

SELECT * FROM [Banana];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets *escape* the database identifier, such as a table name.  For example, if you wanted to name your table using a reserved SQLite keyword, such as `TABLE`, you could escape the name in square brackets:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Table] (
    [Weight] REAL NOT NULL,
    [Color] TEXT DEFAULT 'yellow' NOT NULL,
    [Ripe] BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

In earlier versions of SQLite, you could have used double quotes to achieve the same thing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Table" (
```

Note that in general you should avoid such naming schemes, as you would forever have to escape the table name.

Comment: *In earlier versions of SQLite, you could have used double quotes to achieve the same thing:* And in current versions. Double quotes are the standard way of quoting identifiers; brackets are a MSSQL thing that sqlite accepts too (And it also accepts MySQL style backticks; really should just stick to double quotes though).

Comment: @Shawn To be specific, double quotes are the ANSI standard way to escape.  I agree with everything else you said.